# OBJC_MSGSEND Error in NSString stringWithFormat

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a button in a test iPhone0 application that opens StackOverflow questions based on their GET ID in the URL. Every time the button is pressed, the page should reload to the next question.

I keep count of the GET ID through a `int count` initially set to 1 and incremented every button press.

Hard-coding the URL using: `NSString *urlAddress=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1"];`

works, but obviously doesn't allow for use of the counter. When I try to implement the counter with:

```
NSString *urlAddress =[NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/%@", count];
```

The program fails with the OBJC_MSGSEND error. Why does this line of code not work?

*I have debugged and this is the first line that causes said error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`count` isn't an object.  You need to use `%d`, not `%@`.  Using `%@` as a format specifier means "send a `description` method to the object I've provided as an argument".  Since your variable `count` is not in fact an object, you can't send any messages to it.

Your code (shortened to show the example better), looks like this:

```
NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"something/%@", count];
```

Which is (pretty much) equivalent to this:

```
NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"something/%@", [count description]];
```

As you can imagine, the runtime can't make heads or tails of that (`count` being an `int`, after all).  Using this format will work:

```
NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"something/%d", count];
```